# Can't receive Ether from EtherLi

Tags: ether, internal-transactions

Noob here. I have made two transactions from EtherLi. It looks that they are "stuck" in between. I had enough of gas and the transactions are shown in "internal transactions" but never received at the receivers end.

What could be the problem?

Regards,

Dennis

Comment: To be more specific, it was send as an "internal transaction" instead as an transaction. Is there a way to undo this and reclaim the Ether?